# How could I debug in pycharm in a stable ssh link rather than reconneting ssh each time I debug?

Tags: python, debugging, ssh, pycharm

I'm running deep learning codes.

My pc is poor so I'm using pycharm which connects remote server by ssh.

Here comes the problem:

1. The default server environment doesn't connect to gpu
2. I need to use commond like `salloc --cpus-per-task=4 --gres=gpu:tesla_v100-pcie-32gb:1 -t 20:0:0` to getting into a new environment which connect to gpu.
3. When I press RUN or DEBUG in pycharm, it will start a new ssh connection, rushing into the default environment which doesn't connect to gpu.
   [RUN button and DEBUG button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZU7vS.png)

What I know is that: I can use terminal to salloc and then use commond `python xx.py` to run the script. But what I really want is to use the fantastic DEBUG function of pycharm.[What I know about terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Ha0.png)

What I have tried are as follows:

1. I tried to use `os.system("salloc --cpus-per-task=4 --gres=gpu:tesla_v100-pcie-32gb:1 -t 20:0:0")` at the beginning of python script. But unfortunately, the program stuck after this command, and getting into a shell openned by `salloc`[my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIu2Z.png)    [result after pressing RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DsYi.png)    [the program didn't stop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvvOF.png)
2. I assumed after the operation of 1, the ssh connection should on the salloced session. So I annotated the os code, and stop and RE-RUN. It failed. Maybe pycharm reconnect ssh to the default environment which doesn't connect to gpu.[my modified code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5IBW.png)    [result after RE-RUN](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfZrV.png)

Here is my final question:
How to let pycharm use some command to salloc an environment on the ssh server first and then RUN or DEBUG my code?

Similar discussions can be found here: [Running remote interpreter on a cluster with srun](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000489490-Running-remote-interpreter-on-a-cluster-with-srun)

Comment: Did you find a solution to your problem?